# me sale un error en nodejs, usando la libreria Awilix, en NodeJs, "AwilixTypeError: asClass: expected type to be a class, but got [object Object]

Tags: javascript, nodejs

```
//declarando el contenedor
const container=createContainer();
container.register({
  app:asClass(app).singleton(),
  router: asFunction(Routes).singleton(),
  config: asValue(config)
})
```

Comment: Parece que app no es una clase, sino un objeto "normal"

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente cuando estes exportando dicha clase  en vez de poner ==> new "nombre de clase",
quitale el new para que no la exporte como un objeto de la clase ya que awilix con el "asClass" determina que es una clase y hace todo el trabajo.